# Detecting "powerful" browser which able to do graphics with decent speed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, css

I am builing a mobile HTML5 service where I display polygonial markers on the map image. I animate the markers by drawing then with  and then applying CSS3 animation on .

It was partially success. Devices like Android Galaxy S display animations smoothly, but 2nd gen iPod touches don't. Both feature a WebKit browser with almost similar feature set. The other has 500 MHz GPU 64 MB memory, the other has 1 Ghz CPU and 700 MB memory.

The problem is, how do I separate devices to low- and high end categories. This is more like matter of having memory and CPU and these two facts are never exposed to Javascript (which sucks).

- Can you get easily some kind of rendering speed measurement for the Javascript?
- Any preasembled tables which tells device CPU, memory and acceleration status based on a user agent?

Currently I have added simple heurestics by trying to determine the size of the marker and always fall back to non-animated rectangle on mobile devices. However, this means that a lot of mobile devices will miss the bling bling they could easily do

```
    var pixelAreaThreshold = 200*200;

    var area = (this.bounds[1][0] - this.bounds[0][0]) * (this.bounds[1][1] - this.bounds[0][1]); 

    if(area > pixelAreaThreshold && isMobile()) {
        // <canvas> is very big and may slow down mobile devices
        // (iPod)
        drawUsingCanvas = false;
    }

    var marker;

    if(drawUsingCanvas) {
        // Go for animated polygon if the polygon is small,
        // or if we are using a desktop browser             
        marker = this.drawPolyCanvas(canvas, context)
        marker.addClass("room-marker-animated");
    } else {
        marker = this.drawRectangle();                                                           
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to devise some sort of feature test that runs a relevant animation and then measure its performance (frames per sec or something like that) and store that result.  You can then devise a strategy for what you want to do on that device going forward based on the measured performance (simple graphics vs. complex graphics, etc...).

Such a feature test can even be run in a startup process when the app first starts and can be a visible animation that appears to be part of your normal startup procedure.

Actual feature tests are nearly always better than trying to detect specific devices, processors, clock-rates, GPUs, etc...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499776/is-it-possible-to-benchmark-a-users-system-with-javascript-in-the-browser for elaboration on this approach

Comment: the problem is that Javascript does not expose feature "CPU" :(

Comment: Feature tests are nearly always **better**.

Comment: @lowtechsun - Is that not what my answer says?

Comment: Yes, totally and since I am currently working on something like this I wanted to underline that this approach works. However what happens when the first measured performance **changes** due to less tabs open or more system resources freeing up? One would have to do sort of regular performance tests to not end up serving a low end animation/gif on a high end device that was temporarily clogged.